# iOS 15 app does not receive silent push notification(=background notification)

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, apn

I'm stuck for several days and need your kind help.

I want to receive silent push notifications a.k.a background notifications to update my app content.

Below part in the AppDelegate does not get called.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                   fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult)
                     -> Void) {
     
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")  // Does not get printed
    }

      print("success") // Does not get printed

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
     
}
```

Below is the server-side Python code. Server-side says that sending notification to the device succeeded, so I assume the issue lies in the front-side.

```
def send_notifications_to_fcm_token(fcm_token):
    try:
        message = messaging.Message(
            apns=messaging.APNSConfig(
                headers={
                    'apns-push-type': 'background',
                    'apns-priority': '5',
                },
                payload=messaging.APNSPayload(
                    aps=messaging.Aps(content_available=True)
                ),
            ),
            token=fcm_token,
        )
        response = messaging.send(message)
    except:
        response = False
    return response
```

Some additional notes.

- The following Xcode settings in the "Background Modes" are on:
  "Background fetch", "Remote notifications", "Background processing"
- iPhone's low-data mode and low-power mode are off. (I've read background
  notification does not work if these are on.)
- I succeeded in receiving ordinary (non-silent) push notifications

Let me attach the whole AppDelegate code just in case:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  var window: UIWindow?
  let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication
                     .LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
      
    print("print did finish launching")
      
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    // [START set_messaging_delegate]
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    // [END set_messaging_delegate]
    // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
    // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
    // [START register_for_notifications]
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

      let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: { _, _ in }
      )
    } else {
      let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
      application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    // [END register_for_notifications]
    return true
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
      print("did receive remote notification print user info is \(userInfo)")
  }

  // [START receive_message]
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                   fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult)
                     -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
      
    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    // Print message ID.
      
    //ここはSilent Notificationの設定で通知を送らないとトリガーされない模様
      
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
      print("did receive remote notification long version print user info is \(userInfo)")

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
  }

  // [END receive_message]
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }

  // This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
  // If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
  // the FCM registration token.
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")

    // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
    // Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
  }
}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
  // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions)
                                -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
    // Print full message.
    print("will present print user info is \(userInfo)") 
      
    let categoryId = userInfo["notifications_categories_id"] //as? Int
    //print("category id is \(categoryId!)")

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([[.alert, .sound]])
  }

  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    // Print full message.
      print("did receive print user info is \(userInfo)") 

    completionHandler()
  }
}

// [END ios_10_message_handling]
extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
  // [START refresh_token]
  func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))") 

    let dataDict: [String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(
      name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"),
      object: nil,
      userInfo: dataDict
    )
    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
    // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
  }

  // [END refresh_token]
}
```

EDIT:
I found out this error message is being printed in the console log.
[connection] nw_read_request_report [C2] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"

Comment: did you find a solution??? can you share it

Comment: Any fix did you got for this, as this is a critical feature to update the App content

Comment: I couldn't resolve this issue but I found a workaround to update content via API call whenever the app comes to the foreground from the background, using the  .onChange(of: scenePhase) modifier.